# Should I add sudo before the fastboot command on macOS just like on Linux?

Tags: macos, android, sudo

I will be using `fastboot` on macOS. I will be following t[his tutorial](https://forum.xda-developers.com/z2-play/how-to/stock-stock-firmware-t3630997).

The guide only mentions Windows and Linux, and I do not wish to install those on my Mac right now, and as I think `fastboot` is the same on all platforms, I figure I might just use macOS.

However, the guide says:

> Linux users will need to change the extension to .sh and add sudo
>   before each command or directly run it as root.

Does that apply on macOS also? Should I add `sudo` before each `fastboot` command?

Comment: Try it and see. Adding sudo won't hurt, but it's most likely only needed to ensure access to the USb port, and it might not be needed (I don't have a Mac, so I can't test). If the command does not error without sudi it's fine.

Comment: @davidgo `sudo` and "won't hurt" should never appear in the same sentence.  That's gross irresponsibility.  *Never* use `sudo` unless you know **exactly** what the tool run under it is going to do, and why that is necessary and appropriate.  In this case, it is wrong to do that *even on Linux*.

Comment: @chrisstratton While  your sentiment is sound (running as least privilege), exposing udev rules and modifying groups for single-session access is not exactly trivial and - as the reason for running it with elevated perms is known, it's not exactly a crisis if someone without mad Unix skills uses it on their own box - as is likely the case here. I am sure you know https://xkcd.com/1200/ which somewhat encapsulates my sentiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The command to open a terminal window, (if you follow the guide that uses the android SDK)--in which you will use execute adb--is already under administrative control.  That means that every command entered into terminal will already be using elevated privledges.

Comment: This somewhat mischaracterizes the situation.  While it's true that no extra privileges need to be granted for fastboot or adb from an OSX terminal to interact with an Android device, it should be kept in mind that this *does not* mean that these tools are running as the superuser or that terminal operations have administrative capability in general.  `sudo` in an OSX terminal is a very real tool needed for critical tasks - however, on OSX one already has access to USB devices by default, without having to enable it for specific devices in the fashion needed on most Linuxes.

Answer (score 0):

No.  And you should not use `sudo` with `fastboot` on Linux, either.

The `fastboot` client tool was never intended to be run as the superuser.  Even its authors do not promote it as suitable for that purpose.  If you look at the code within the Android offerings that *is* intended to run as the superuser (on the device itself) it is written quite differently.

Rather, on Linux you should use a *udev rule* to expose Android USB devices (both ADB ID's and the differing fastboot ones) to those user(s) authorized to work with them.  The Android documentation explains how to set up and activate the needed rules.

In a pinch, if you're really too lazy to set it up right, use `sudo` to temporarily give your user access to the USB device node, then run `fastboot` under your user id - though you'll have to do this again if you re-plug the device or if it re-enumerates, for example when changing between fastboot and ADB modes.

**In contrast, the situation on a Mac differs**, in that the system by default *already* gives your user permission to USB peripherals, so no system configuration is needed to make this work.

On either system, once properly configured (by default on a Mac, by proper setup on Linux), you should be running `fastboot` and `adb` under your normal user account, ie without `sudo`.